# GDB can't break strcpy()?

Tags: gcc, gdb

so im trying to debug this simple c program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){

char str_a[20];

strcpy(str_a,"Hello, world!\n");        
printf(str_a);

return 0;}
```

gcc -g -o prog prog.c

gdb -q ./prog

```
(gdb) list
1   #include<stdio.h>
2   #include<string.h>
3   
4   int main(){
5   
6       char str_a[20];
7       
8       strcpy(str_a,"Hello, world!\n");        
9       printf(str_a);
10  
(gdb) break 7
Breakpoint 1 at 0x757: file char_array.c, line 7.
(gdb) break strcpy
Function "strcpy" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Breakpoint 2 (strcpy) pending.
(gdb) break 9
Breakpoint 3 at 0x76a: file char_array.c, line 9.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/pinguino/Desktop/char_array 

Breakpoint 1, main () at char_array.c:8
8       strcpy(str_a,"Hello, world!\n");        
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 3, main () at char_array.c:9
9       printf(str_a);
```

As u can see it entirely skips the strcpy breakpoint...
This question has already been posted on sites like stackoverflow but none of the answers there helped me: I've tried adding -fno-builtin but no results whatsoever. Help, I'm lost.

Some more info: 
 uname --all
Linux 4.10.0-33-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 11 10:55:28 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably not a Ubuntu specific question, so please have a look at [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25272964/2069348).

If that code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){

char str_a[20];

strcpy(str_a,"Hello, world!\n");        
printf(str_a);

return 0;}
```

is really the code you're trying to debug, `gcc` is probably clever enough
to have simpified your code as `printf("Hello world\n"); return 0`, or simply use the builtin for `strcpy`.

So try `--no-builtin`, perphaps with `-O0`, it is at least working on `gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609`.

You can use `objdump -d prog` to see the disassembly of your code, there is no call to `strcpy` here.

**For this question in particular**

You're using `break 7`, but the line is empty, using `break 8` should work.

Comment: So first of all thank you.  I've tried  --no-builtin and -o0 but they dont work. I remember having tried break 8 but it gave me the: " Note: breakpoint 1 also set at pc 0x757." and now I've understood that is due to the breakpoint at line 7, removing that, I was simply able to break 8
 and you are right again in saying that there is no call to strcpy().